# How can a promise be returned by a dialog popup in angularjs Material Design?

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I was reading up on details of mdDialog in Material Design, and couldn't understand why an alert popup would return a promise. **Can someone explain how a promise is returned by a mdDialog through an example?**

The documentation for Material Design mdDialog said the following:

> $mdDialog opens a dialog over the app to inform users about critical information or require them to make decisions. There are two approaches for setup: a simple promise API and regular object syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns a `promise` because you probably want to react to future events in different way, like `close` (resolve the promise) and `cancel` (reject it).

`mdDialod.show()` returns a promise, as written in documentation, so you can just resolve or reject it (as mentioned above, with `close` and `cancel` methods on `$mdDialog` service).

[Here is a simple example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdEvjx) as you requested (open the console to see how it logs the appropriate text for each event).

Comment: What is the promise being returned in the example you gave?

Comment: `$mdDialog.show()`. note the `then` chained to right after it's called. you should read about the promise's implementation by angular team https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 5):

The docs were a little vague I thought, but here is how I got it working.

in baseController:

```
$mdDialog.show({/*modalOptions*/})
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }).finally(function() {
    // finally block is optional for cleanup
  });
```

in modal controller

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
  $mdDialog.cancel('user pressed canceled');
};

$scope.ok = function () {
  $mdDialog.hide({message: 'here is some result data'});
};
```